Is it possible to set the reply-to field on an ad-hoc basis when composing email in Gmail?
Sometimes I want to send an email from my Gmail account using a particular reply-to address, but only occasionally.
Is there any way to set that, ad-hoc, when composing the email?
(Am aware that I can configure a permanent reply-to for my main address, or set up an alias with a given reply-to then select that as the From address when composing, but seems a long way around.)

No, the options to change the reply-to address are limited to the
"Send mail as" section of Gmail Settings > Accounts and Import
You will need to use the "edit info" link for an existing account or add an a new alias.
